# Error When GetChanges Method does not return any row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView based on table Table1 of DataSet DS1. When I make changes to DataGridView and press CancelChanges button, it works fine. But if there are no changes in the DataGridView(i.e. GetChanges() method will not return any rows) and I press CancelChanges button, it throws following error:-

> "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object"

on the line `if (DgvChangedDT.Rows.Count != 0)`

```
private void btnCancelChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable DgvChangedDT = new DataTable();
        DgvChangedDT = DS1.Table1.GetChanges();
        if (DgvChangedDT.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            DS1.Table1.RejectChanges();
            DS1.Table1.AcceptChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There are no pending changes.");
        }
    }
```

Can Someone tell me the reason of the error and remedy for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code:

```
private void btnCancelChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable DgvChangedDT = new DataTable();
    DgvChangedDT = DS1.Table1.Changes();
    if (DgvChangedDT != null && DgvChangedDT.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        DS1.Table1.RejectChanges();
        DS1.Table1.AcceptChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are no pending changes.");
    }
}
```

Since u was missing null check for `DgvChangedDT`, if user dont make changes in dgv then `DS1.Table1.Changes();` will return null value.